# Como pasar parámetro tabla sql en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas necesito hacer una consulta que seleccione el nombre de la tabla en base a un comboBox, el problema lo tengo en que es una consulta muy larga y tengo bastantes más, por lo que necesito una forma fácil de pasarle el nombre de la tabla, he intentado algo así pero no funciona:

```
  query = @";with temporalCTE
                as
                ( 
               SELECT Q.AÑO, Q.MES, q.DIA, q.HORA, SUM(q.PARTICULAS) AS PARTICULAS , SUM(q.PRESION) AS PRESION
                           FROM (
                           SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA)AS AÑO,DATEPART(MONTH,Fecha) as MES, DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) as DIA, datepart(hour, Fecha) as hora, CONVERT(decimal(10,2), AVG(particulas)) as PARTICULAS, 0 as PRESION
                           FROM '" + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+

                @"' WHERE flag1 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA), DATEPART(MONTH, Fecha), DATEPART(DAY, Fecha), DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha)  having count(flag1)>45
                           UNION
                           SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA)AS AÑO, DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) AS MES, DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) as Hora,datepart(hour, Fecha) as hora, 0 AS PARTICULAS,CONVERT(decimal(10,2), AVG(presion)) AS PRESION                      
                           FROM '" + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+

                @"'WHERE flag2 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta  GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA), DATEPART(MONTH, Fecha), DATEPART(DAY, Fecha), DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha) having count(flag2)>45

                           ) q 
                           GROUP BY Q.AÑO, Q.MES, q.DIA, Q.hora


                )

                SELECT M.AÑO, M.MES, 
                                          m.DIA, SUM(m.PARTICULAS) AS PARTICULAS , SUM(m.PRESION) AS PRESION
                   FROM (
                select  AÑO, MES, DIA , CONVERT(decimal(10,2),avg(particulas)) AS PARTICULAS, 0 AS PRESION
                from temporalCTE WHERE PARTICULAS > 0 group by AÑO, MES, DIA
                union 
                select AÑO, MES, DIA, 0  AS PARTICULAS, CONVERT(decimal(10,2),AVG(PRESION)) AS PRESION
                from temporalCTE WHERE PRESION > 0 group by AÑO, MES,  DIA
                )m group by M.AÑO, M.MES, m.dia

                ";
```

También he intentado pasárselo como parámetro pero me da error diciendo que debe declararse la variable de tabla

```
        query = @";with temporalCTE
                as
                ( 
               SELECT Q.AÑO, Q.MES, q.DIA, q.HORA, SUM(q.PARTICULAS) AS PARTICULAS , SUM(q.PRESION) AS PRESION
                           FROM (
                           SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA)AS AÑO,DATEPART(MONTH,Fecha) as MES, DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) as DIA, datepart(hour, Fecha) as hora, CONVERT(decimal(10,2), AVG(particulas)) as PARTICULAS, 0 as PRESION
                           FROM @filtro

                 WHERE flag1 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA), DATEPART(MONTH, Fecha), DATEPART(DAY, Fecha), DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha)  having count(flag1)>45
                           UNION
                           SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA)AS AÑO, DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) AS MES, DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) as Hora,datepart(hour, Fecha) as hora, 0 AS PARTICULAS,CONVERT(decimal(10,2), AVG(presion)) AS PRESION                      
                           FROM @filtro

                WHERE flag2 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta  GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, FECHA), DATEPART(MONTH, Fecha), DATEPART(DAY, Fecha), DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha) having count(flag2)>45

                           ) q 
                           GROUP BY Q.AÑO, Q.MES, q.DIA, Q.hora


                )

                SELECT M.AÑO, M.MES, 
                                          m.DIA, SUM(m.PARTICULAS) AS PARTICULAS , SUM(m.PRESION) AS PRESION
                   FROM (
                select  AÑO, MES, DIA , CONVERT(decimal(10,2),avg(particulas)) AS PARTICULAS, 0 AS PRESION
                from temporalCTE WHERE PARTICULAS > 0 group by AÑO, MES, DIA
                union 
                select AÑO, MES, DIA, 0  AS PARTICULAS, CONVERT(decimal(10,2),AVG(PRESION)) AS PRESION
                from temporalCTE WHERE PRESION > 0 group by AÑO, MES,  DIA
                )m group by M.AÑO, M.MES, m.dia

                ";

                cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaDesde", Convert.ToDateTime(dateDatosDiariosDesde.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"))));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaHasta", Convert.ToDateTime(dateDatosDiariosHasta.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"))));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filtro", Convert.ToString(cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower())));
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dataGridDiarios.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

De las dos maneras me da error, y necesito algo para no estar poniendo comillas al principio y final de cada linea

Comment: No termino de entender que es lo que intentas conseguir. ¿Intentas conseguir nombres de las tablas? ¿ A partir de un dato en un combo box llamar a BD?

Comment: si, tengo varias tablas con las mismas columnas, necesito que en base a un combo box que tengo me haga la consulta de una tabla o de otra (filtro1, filtro2, filtro3, filtro5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la primera consulta, bueno, el string que contiene la consulta, veo un par de errores:

Entendiendo que el objeto `cbFiltrosDatosDiarios` contiene el nombre de la tabla, debes quitar las comillas simples que rodean desde el `FROM` hasta el `WHERE` y dejarlo como sigue:

```
FROM " + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+
@" WHERE flag1 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta GROUP
```

en vez de

```
FROM '" + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+
@"' WHERE flag1 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta GROUP
```

Por otra parte falta un espacio en el segundo `WHERE`, además de requerir quitar las comillas simples.:

```
FROM " + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+
@" WHERE flag2 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta  GROUP
```

en vez de

```
FROM '" + cbFiltrosDatosDiarios.Text.Trim().ToLower()+
@"'WHERE flag2 ='0'  AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta  GROUP BY
```

Comment: Gracias! asi funciona, no hay ninguna manera de pasar el nombre de la tabla como parámetro al igual que paso la fecha?

Comment: Que yo sepa no es posible. Otra cosa es que metieras la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado y le pasases el nombre de la tabla como parámetro.

Comment: Lo estudiaré, gracias